# Cant install laravel on kali linux

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

These codes which I have written terminal

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e115a8dc7871f15d853148a7fbac7da27d6c0030b848d9b3dc09e2a0388afed865e6a3d6b3c0fad45c48e2b5fc1196ae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Composer is working.

After that I downloaded laravel without error.

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

But When I write *~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel* in terminal it gives me error

```
bash: /root/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel: No such file or directory
```

Where is my problem?I dont get it.

EDIT:

*find /root/ -name laravel*

```
./.config/composer/vendor/bin/laravel
./.config/composer/vendor/laravel
./.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel
./.cache/composer/files/laravel
```

Comment: Can you run `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`?

Comment: @spicydog yes it is working(Created project in blog ...)Also please check my question I also shared find -name laravel command

Comment: I don't know why you are looking for the files in `/root/.composer/` It should be in your Laravel isn't it? Suppose that you have run my command, you will get `blog` directory. After that, go into that directory and run `php artisan serve`. The Laravel should be online. Have you check Laravel documents yet? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3

Comment: @spicydog Yes I am online http://localhost:8000/ thank you for help

Comment: Sure, I will write it as the answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply run `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` to install Laravel in `blog` directory.

Then you go into `blog` directory and run `php artisan serve`. Now your Laravel should already be online.

Check this document for the Laravel installation https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/#installing-laravel.