# laravel/framework requires ext-mbstring

Tags: laravel, installation, laravel-5.5

I am using Kali linux and I am having difficulty installing the laravel framework. I havelooked up in different links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40357524/cant-install-laravel-on-kali-linux) one and manyothers but nothing seems to work. For every this I do. It keeps bringing this error

```
laravel/framework v5.5.9 requires ext-mbstring -> ...
...
```

For instance:

```
root@iO-PC:/opt/lampp/htdocs/projects# composer create-project laravel/laravel Test "5.5.*"
```

On processing.. This is what shows up.

```
    Installing laravel/laravel (v5.5.28)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.5.28): Loading from cache
Created project in Test
> @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.5.9 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.8 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.7 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.6 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.5 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.36 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.35 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.34 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.33 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.32 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.31 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.30 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.29 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.28 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.27 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.26 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.25 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.24 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.23 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.22 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.21 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.20 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.19 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.18 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.17 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.16 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.15 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.14 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.13 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.12 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.11 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.10 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.0, v5.5.1, v5.5.10, v5.5.11, v5.5.12, v5.5.13, v5.5.14, v5.5.15, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.18, v5.5.19, v5.5.2, v5.5.20, v5.5.21, v5.5.22, v5.5.23, v5.5.24, v5.5.25, v5.5.26, v5.5.27, v5.5.28, v5.5.29, v5.5.3, v5.5.30, v5.5.31, v5.5.32, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.4, v5.5.5, v5.5.6, v5.5.7, v5.5.8, v5.5.9].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

What do I have to fix this?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Install the required  **mbstring** extension

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

In Dockerfile you should add:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring
```

Comment: This time it says `phpunit/phpunit 6.5.7 requires ext-dom -> ...`

Comment: requires what ? rest of the sentence ?

Comment: Replace `laravel/framework v5.5.1 requires ext-mbstring` with `phpunit/phpunit 6.5.7 requires ext-dom`

Comment: But I used `sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml` and it works just fine now. But for some reason, it didnt work before even when I used the `sudo apt-get install php-mbstring`. But I think it was that I was installing laravel 5.5.* (which requires php >= 7.1.3) and I had 7.0.1 installed.

Comment: Thank you for bringing light to my problem.

Comment: Is there difference between `php-mbstring` and `php7.2-mbstring` since I have PHP 7.2 set up as default?

Comment: @vintproykt No differance, it will install the default one

Answer (score 19):

`sudo apt install php-mbstring` will work and will download the plugin for the latest PHP version.

If your PHP version is not the latest, then you can add version in it:

```
# PHP 7.3
sudo apt install php7.3-mbstring

# PHP 7.4
sudo apt install php7.3-mbstring

# PHP 8.0
sudo apt install php8.0-mbstring

# PHP 8.1
sudo apt install php8.1-mbstring

# PHP 8.2
sudo apt install php8.2-mbstring

# PHP 8.3:
sudo apt install php-mbstring
```

Comment: In my case, i had both php8.0 and php7.4 but i had configured my system to use php8.0. 
When i run `sudo apt install php-mbstring`, this install php-mbstring for php.0. To get it for php7.4, i did `sudo apt install php7.3-mbstring` and the problem was solved.

Comment: In my case, for php8.1, `php8.1-mbstring` as the latest possible naming did not work but `php-mbstring` did. That goes along with what you write here: the latest php version is just `php-`, and only previous versions can be fixed.

Comment: Specifying the version of php works fine. However you may still encounter other errors for packages or extensions missing on your system. You may consider updating the composer version

Answer (score 10):

I have the same problem when installing Laravel 6 and getting an error like this

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v6.12.0)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v6.12.0): Loading from cache
Created project in sistemLogin
> @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v6.9.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.8.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.7.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.6.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.6.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.6.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.5.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.5.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.5.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.4.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.4.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.3.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.2.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.17.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.17.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.16.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.15.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.15.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.14.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.13.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.13.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.12.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.11.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.10.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.10.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework 6.x-dev requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework ^6.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v6.10.0, v6.10.1, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v6.9.0].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

And I try command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

After that I tried again install laravel and there were still problems like this

```
    Installing laravel/laravel (v6.12.0)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v6.12.0): Loading from cache
Created project in sistemLogin
> @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit 8.5.x-dev requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 8.5.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 8.5.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 8.5.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    ...........
```

So if like that, you can try command

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install php-xml
```

then run

```
composer update
composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable
```

[PHP7 : install ext-dom issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408604/php7-install-ext-dom-issue)