# PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system

Tags: php, laravel, mbstring

I am getting this error.

```
laravel/framework v5.4.9 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is 
missing from your system.
```

So I followed this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49087941/14505740
And used

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

But I am still getting the same error when I run `composer install` I am using `laravel 5.4` and PHP `7.2.34`

Comment: Did you uncomment it in php.ini?

Comment: you mean this `;extension=mbstring` ?

Comment: yes, you need to remove comment (semicolon) from the beginning, after save of course it requires Apache's restart

Comment: probably you didn't install it for the correct PHP version.

Comment: @VijayRathore what is the correct way to install mbsring for PHP `7.2.34`

Comment: @biesior: I uncommented and restarted apached too. but still getting  error: `laravel/framework v5.4.9 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php-mbstring` should take care of all the settings, as long as you installed PHP from the same source. Is it actually installed? It should show up when you type `php -m` (command-line) or in `phpinfo()`.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring`

Comment: Ensure you are installing the correct version of the extension for your PHP version, and also that you are restarting the web server and/or PHP-FPM after making changes.